# Angular createEmbeddedView is not rendering the view at correct index instead it is rendering at last index

Tags: angular, components, angular-directive, renderer

I have a parent component with number of child components and one of the child component is having a custom structural directive "accessible" as shown in below code.

For suppose,

```
<my-table>
    <div myTableColumn></div>
    <div myTableColumn *accessible="'user'"></div>
    <div myTableColumn></div>
    <div myTableColumn></div>
</my-table>
```

Here,
structural directive accessible is written as

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[accessible]'
})

constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
) {}

@Input() set accessible(val) {
    if (val === 'user') {
        this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
        this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    }
}
```

But this is rendering  with structural directive (i.e. second column) at the last index.

How to pass index to the createEmbeddedView to insert the template at correct index. But passing index in the above code doesnt seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you inject the `ViewContainerRef` from `my-table`? Then, I think you can specify the index. Maybe adding `@Self()` to `ViewContainerRef` would help. If not, could you create a StackBlitz demo or something like that?

Comment: @AndreiGătej I tried both the solutions but it didnt help me. I will try to create demo and share it soon

Comment: @AndreiGătej I just checked the children i.e. my-table-columns are not added into _embeddedViews array. Whereas the createEmbeddedView is adding second index child into embeddedView array of viewContainerRef.